# Может ли "высокозадранный" писаться слитно?

Tags: грамматика

Встречала слитное написание: "высокозадранный". Это правильно? Если да, то чем определяется слитное/раздельное написание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

П р а в и л о: наречие с прилагательным и причастием пишется раздельно.
Например: быстро бегущий человек, однозначно понимаемый текст, совершенно черная кошка, абсолютно неадекватное поведение, высоко задранная юбка, высоко задранный нос.

Вот что поясняют Н. С. Валгина и В. Н. Светлышева в справочнике по орфографии и пунктуации.

Слитно пишутся сложные прилагательные, которые употребляются как термины или в составе терминологических выражений. Первая часть таких прилагательных представлена наречным словом на **о** или **е**, вторая — прилагательным или причастием:
**высоко-** — *высокооплачиваемый, высококультурный, высоконравственный, высокоодаренный, высокопродуктивный, высокопрофессиональный;* основа **высоко-** как часть сложного прилагательного употребляется в значении 'в высшей степени' и, в отличие от наречия высок**о**, имеет ударение на втором слоге: выс**о**коорбит**а**льный.
[Правописание сложных слов](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.48)

Я считаю слитное написание ошибочным — это не термин, а представить себе произношение слова *выс**о**коз**а**дранный* невозможно.
[В словаре Ушакова: задранный — прич. страд. прош. вр. от *задрать* (***разг.***).]

*Минуты через две я услышал далекий ноющий звук мотора. Затем показалась и лодка **с высоко задранным** острым носом и одинокой фигурой человека* (В. Г. Распутин).

*Несмотря на нелёгкую ношу, гусак вышагивал гордо, неся свою жертву **на высоко задранной** шее* (Е. Корджева).

*Корабли разошлись в каких-то тридцати метрах друг от друга. **Круто задранный** вверх нос крейсера затмил скромно выглянувший из-за туч и линии горизонта ущербный кусочек солнца, и волна от буруна ракетоносца заметно качнула фрегат* (Е. П. Сартинов).

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае наречие **высоко** может только характеризовать выраженное причастием *действие* и не может быть перенесено на свойства существительного, на которое это действие направлено. Поэтому *причастие* не переходит в *прилагательное*, которое описывало бы *свойство* существительного (нельзя представить себе устойчивое свойство "высокозадранности"), и пишется **раздельно**  с наречием. Похожий пример можно вспомнить из области хоккея, где игроков иногда наказывают за "игру **высоко поднятой** клюшкой" - и здесь причастие выражает лишь подверженность действию, но не свойство.

Иное наблюдается в случае напр. "высокопоставленности": **высоко поставленный** предмет (явно выраженное причастие, акцент на *действии*), но **высокопоставленный** чиновник (во втором случае причастие по смыслу переходит в сложное прилагательное, характеризующее *свойство* - общественное положение человека).